# Jquery datepicker not working on focus on textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to create an example datepicker in Jquery, however i'm not being successful, any help on where i'm going wrong?

I have 2 files: 
html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="datepicker-ar.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ar" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;
  <select id="locale">
    <option value="ar">Arabic (&#8235;(&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1577;</option>
    <option value="">English</option>
  </select></p>


</body>
</html>
```

JS: datepicker-ar.js:

```
/* Arabic Translation for jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Used in most of Arab countries, primarily in Bahrain, Kuwait, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia and the United Arab Emirates, Egypt, Sudan and Yemen. */
/* Written by Mohammed Alshehri -- m@dralshehri.com */

( function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "../widgets/datepicker" ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery.datepicker );
    }
}( function( datepicker ) {

datepicker.regional.ar = {
    closeText: "إغلاق",
    prevText: "&#x3C;السابق",
    nextText: "التالي&#x3E;",
    currentText: "اليوم",
    monthNames: [ "يناير", "فبراير", "مارس", "أبريل", "مايو", "يونيو",
    "يوليو", "أغسطس", "سبتمبر", "أكتوبر", "نوفمبر", "ديسمبر" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12" ],
    dayNames: [ "الأحد", "الاثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة", "السبت" ],
    dayNamesShort: [ "أحد", "اثنين", "ثلاثاء", "أربعاء", "خميس", "جمعة", "سبت" ],
    dayNamesMin: [ "ح", "ن", "ث", "ر", "خ", "ج", "س" ],
    weekHeader: "أسبوع",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: true,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: "" };
datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional.ar );

return datepicker.regional.ar;

} ) );
```

[image]

This is the example i'm trying to recreate: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

When referencing jquery 1.10.2 only, i'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: You're loading two versions of jQuery. Either don't do that, or make use of `jQuery.noConflict()` to resolve them.

Comment: @Barmar when i was loading only one version, it also wasn't working.

Comment: It looks like jQuery UI may not be getting loaded properly.

Comment: Have you tried to put the script at the end of body?

Comment: @daB0bby yes same result

Comment: Is jquery working, if you don't include jquery-ui?